# seaborn jointplot with arrays of different length

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to draw joint distribution of 2 variables in a package named seaborn (a wrapper over matplotlib). Ultimately, I want to get something like this: http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/hexbin_marginals.html

The problem is that seaborn swears at me when I pass arrays of different lengths. Suppose,

```
var1 = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,5,7]
var2 = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,9,10,13]
```

Then if I write this:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.jointplot(var1, var2, kind='hex')
```

it throws

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (13) (20)
```

Anyone knows how to make seaborn reconcile with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL/DR: Joint plots are not a well-defined mathematical operation when the arrays are of different lengths**

You can think of hexbin as a scatterplot, except instead of plotting dots, it slightly increases the value of the hexagonal area the dot would otherwise fall into. Obviously, unless all your x's are paired with y's, you can't make a scatter plot.

*mathy answer:*

In that plot, if you look at the histogram to the top and the right, that is the unidimensional frequency distribution. The point of plotting the 2D distribution in the main window is to see how the variable might be dependent--if they are independent, then each (x,y) coordinate is simple the relative frequency of the x variable, times the relative frequency of the y variable (ie the pdf `f(x,y) = f(x)f(y)` for x,y indep).

So if you want to see how these variable deviate from being independent, you have to have joint information about them--joint meaning observations of both variable have a common index, here assumed to be (0...i). See also [independence on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) and [the independence tag on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independence?sort=votes).

Comment: Totally agree with you - my question is really silly and should be deleted :)